# iOs : Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin

Tags: ios, html, iframe, youtube

**I know this question has been asked and answered a million times**. But. Right now, I'm testing a website that has got some Youtube iframe embeds on iOs. It looks like :

```
<iframe width="100%" height="200" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/my-video-id" class="yt-player-listed " frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So, **just the basic code provided by Youtube**. It works fine on most devices. But on iOs Safari :

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin ... from html5player.js:816
```

I don't see any protocol mismatch, as long as I'm using `//` (I also tried with http: and https:) : **the iframe just doesn't appear**.

I tried :

1. changed the protocol (http, https, //)
2. removed all attribute in the iframe (allowfullscreen, frameborder)

I don't know what's going on there...

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with Safari implementation on iFrame. Safari fixed this issue.
It should work now without throwing any console errors.
Github issue: [https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/issues/588][Closed]